# Are HAML and Sass requirements for working with Compass?

Tags: dependencies, haml, sass, compass-sass

How interdependent are Haml, Sass and Compass?

Are all three required in a Compass project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Compass](http://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/master) needs sass to work. But your html markup does not have to be in haml. Sass and haml ship in the same gem.

After you set up your stylesheets with compass, you are done, there is no requirement to have sass/haml on your production machine.